# new to java regex, how to grab this part of the string

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I have a string that looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/index.do/blah/1_44/asdf/asdf/asdf
http://www.example.com/index.do/blah/1_44_2342/asdf/asdf/asdf
```

I need to grab the value 44 from the above, ofcourse '44' could be any number.
The number '44' always is prefixed with a `_`, and after it could be another `_` or `/`.

I have no idea of the java regex API, so as guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's primarily the [`Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes you're interested in.

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/index.do/blah/1_44/asdf/asdf/asdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
  int number = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
}
```

This pattern finds the first sequence of one or more digits after the first `_`.